# Custom video transitions

Tags: video

I want to make custom video transition like page turn effect in blender video editor, how to to do it? like making album where one page turn and you can see the next page

Comment: Not sure that's something that can be done in the video editor. Page turning isn't one of the available transitions as far as I know. It's really something that requires animation of the pages and then the animation to be rendered into a video file.

Comment: Yup the only way I can see it happening in Blender is using a real model of a 3D page with a texture applied to it in the 3D viewport and use a camera to export it as an animation

Comment: Maybe render a page-turn just for a UV-pass in the compositor, as a general-purpose wipe between image-sequences.. still not just 'pushing a button' though.. but, at least re-usable.

Answer (score 1):

Add an Image as plane, turn its image texture material node to "Movie" or "Image sequence" and load the movie, set the shader as emission 1.0, subdivide the plane as much as needed to deform it.

Add a Camera, clear its loc and rot (Alt G, Alt R) and rise it above the plane. set it to ortographic and adjust the scale.

Set the resolution of the output and in the color management the View transform to "Standard" and the look to "None".

Now you can invent any kind of animation to create the transition file.

[image]

Comment: that's actually a great idea!!

Comment: Thanks Josh, animation is not a problem, if i have 20sec video, the last 3 sec i make page turn animation and when add to the vedio file, the deffrence in two video is obvious